# Clients with empty username are not receiving request new password email

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration, password, phpmyadmin

I am looking after a old site from a client and a lot of users dont have username.

I had setup in woocommerce "When creating an account, automatically generate a username from the customer's email address", but for some reason it is not creating username for the new user, so I unticked that and left the field mandatory.

Now, If an user with blank username request a new password, wordpress doesnt send an email. Only if I go manually to the phpmyadmin and included it. However there are more than 500 users without username. Is there a way to automatically get the user email for example and include in the username field?

Or make wordpress send email even with no username?

Thank you,

Comment: I mean "user_login"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress functions doesn't allow to modify user login then you need to change directly the database.

make a backup of you database and try this to fill login with something like `user4589`

```
UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_login` = CONCAT("user", ID) WHERE `user_login` = ""
```

Comment: Thank you for replaying, I am not good using phpmyadmin, I went to the wp_users table, click on SQL tab and paste the code you informed. But I got this error: SQL query:

UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_login` = CONCAT("user", ID), WHERE `user_login` = ""
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `user_login` = ""' at line 1

Comment: I had to remove the comma before WHERE and it works. Thank you